# Why response.item[*].id doesn't work in karate JsonPath

Tags: karate, jsonpath

for the example https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#path-examples, `$.store.book[*].author` can return authors of all books;
But it doesn't work on my code: `* print transactionIds = response.items[*].id`

In my response, there are 100 items returned, and individual record id is able to print out by giving index number e.g. "*print response.items[0].id"

But I want to get all records ids and put in a new array, just like the JsonPath#path-examples to get all authors of all books.

Why response.items[*].id doesn't work for me in Karate API testing?

Answer (score 0):

JsonPath on the right-hand-side needs a `$` prefix. Try this:

```
* def transactionIds = $response.items[*].id
* print transactionIds
```

Please refer the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#get